# How can we find target URL from links that redirect after delay?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

We can use cURL to find target URL of a URL that redirects instantly like with 301. But if a web page redirects after some delay for example with Javascript then how can we find target URL that finally loads. I tried with `iframe` but src of `iframe` don't change on redirection.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src;
```

Any possible solution using Javascript or PHP?

Parsing target content don't seem feasible as redirection code can be in externally linked js file and also redirection code can be with any function in obfuscated form.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way except running all JS code on your side.

Comment: Oh, JS will also be dependent of that webpage's dom, means this is not possible at all?

Comment: You could run the page in a headless browser and read out the url after some time...